# Pause music on keyboard input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an audio source attached to my game object and i want the music to pause when the keyboard up arrow is pressed and unpause when the keyboard down arrow is pressed.

Why is this not working?

```
public class pauseMusic : MonoBehaviour {


public AudioSource audio;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        audio.pause();
    }


    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        audio.UnPause();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: please be sure to remember to click "Tick" on any useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't capitalize the "p" of of pause. So your program doesn't recognize the [Pause](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Pause.html) function.

You by the way probably prefer to use the [GetKeyDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) method over the [GetKey](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) one, as you want to pause or unpause your audio only once, and not everytime you enter in your update.

```
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        audio.Pause();
    }


    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        audio.UnPause();
    }
}
```